# What HTML element to use for holding hidden values

Tags: html

In my application I have a need to keep some values hidden, for them to be later picked up by jQuery.

I have a following div for keeping map's data (after `img` is clicked I would like to show a map with 2 markers):

```
<div class="map-data">
<img src="../map.png">
</div>
```

In order to do that I need to store 4 hidden values (`1_lat, 1_long, 2_lat, 2_long`), like:

```
<label type="hidden" value="56.056180">
```

What would the right hidden element be for storing such values? `Label`, `p` or something else?

Comment: A `data` attribute can be used on any element.  Or you could use an `input type="hidden"` if you'd like.  Or even just put it in a JavaScript variable instead of storing it in the markup.  There are many options available, really.

Comment: JavaScript? `config = { lat1: "1234" ...`

Comment: Use `input` . e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="1_lat" value="56.056180">` . If it's in a form, than you can call that value in POST or GET .. your choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it seems that you will only use those values client-side, i.e. you are not going to send them back to the server, it seems wrong to me to use an `input` element.

The comments already have two very good advice, here expanded.

---

Personally I would use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) if I needed **per-element** data (data that varies per element).

```
<div id="sampleMap" data-lat1="0.241" data-lat2="0.56">
   ...
</div>

<div id="anotherSampleMap" data-lat1="0.87" data-lat2="0.283">
   ...
</div>
```

They can be accessed very easily.

```
function configureTheMap(map)
{
    var lat1 = map.dataset.lat1;
    var lat2 = map.dataset.lat2; 

    ...
}

...

configureTheMap(document.getElementById('sampleMap'));
configureTheMap(document.getElementById('anotherSampleMap'));
```

You should check browser compatibility though.

If the data was **global** I would simply generate a JavaScript object

```
var coordinates_config = {lat1 : 0.241, lat2 : 0.56};
```

and use it accordingly

```
function configureTheMap(map)
{
    var lat1 = coordinates_config.lat1;
    var lat2 = coordinates_config.lat2; 

    ...
}
```

You can generalize this method easily to be used for *per-element* data if *data attributes* are not supported by the browsers you are targeting.

In both cases, allow me to remember the importance of proper escaping when generating the markup/code.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use an input box of type hidden for this purpose:

```
<input id='1_lat' type="hidden" value="56.056180">
```

You can then update this value with `$("#1_lat").val("22.0")`

Comment: There are no jQuery tags on this post. It would be better to provide `document.getElementById("1_lat").value = "22.0";`

Comment: @user2867288 OP specifically states "for them to be later picked up by jQuery"

Answer (score 1):

`<input id='input_ID' type="hidden" value="whateveryouwant">`

in dreamweaver you can use it as gui drag and drop from the php toolbox on the right

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input type="hidden".
reference: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you always use INPUT for the hidden values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternatives as follow :

1. `<input>`[element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)
2. [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes](https://robertnyman.com/2010/04/29/using-html5-custom-data-attributes-to-store-data-on-html-elements/)
3. [Custom non-visible data with data attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)